# Pyserial and QUERY Issues

Tags: pyserial

I have a MKS pressure transducer with a 9 pin DB connector.  The user interface is through RS-232 or RS-485 serial communications.  I am currently developing code using pyserial and python to query the transducer via a plugable RS-232 to usb adaptor.  I'm sure the adaptor works because I have used it for communicating with another instrument via pyserial.

The relevant pins for the transducer are:

```
3 - POWER +
4 - POWER -
6 - RELAY COMMON
7 - RS485 - / RS232 TXD
9 - RS485 + / RS232 RXD
```

My adaptor is connected to /dev/ttyUSB1.

The transducer has a factory default baud rate = 9600, the data format is 8 data bits, no parity and one stop bit.  Based on the manual the query and command syntax are the same for RS485 and RS232.

The problem that I am having is querying the transducer.

The syntax required for a query is:

```
@<device address><query>?;FF
```

For example to Query current baud rate:  @253BR?;FF

Where:

```
@ <attention charector>
253 <default address>
BR? <query for baud rate>
;FF <terminator>
```

My python code is:

```
import serial 

Piezo = serial.Serial(port ='/dev/ttyUSB1',
                         baudrate=9600,parity =serial.PARITY_NONE,
                         stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                         timeout =1)

print Piezo.isOpen()

Piezo.write('@253BR?;FF')
print Piezo.readall()
Piezo.close()
```

With my response:

%run /home/vivekd/Desktop/Software/Pressure/Piezon.py
True

unfortunately I do not get a response back, I am assuming it has to do with the write sequence and the non-traditional terminator.  I have tried other write combo's but I get no response.  Any and all suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks.

-V

Comment: Is it possible that the `FF` is intended to be 'form feed', i.e. the character `'\f'`, or maybe a hexadecimal ASCII code, i.e. character number 0xFF?

Comment: I do believe the FF is a form feed and I did try \f utilizing: Piezo.write('@253BR?;' + '\f')
print Piezo.readall()...With no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the issue was the rs232 sent and received pin wiring were backwards.